# homotopy group of the limit space

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits, algebraic-topology, convergence-divergence, fiber-bundles

Let $V_k(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ be Stiefel manifold. Using $\pi_i(V_k(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}))=0$ for all $i\leq n-1$, how to obtain $\pi_i( V_k(\mathbb{R}^{\infty}))=0$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$? Can I just write formally
$\pi_i(\lim_{n\to\infty}V_k(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi_i(V_k(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}))$?

Comment: It looks like this would follow from the main result of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4713) which says that if $M$ is a union of an ascending infinite chain of manifolds $M_n$, and satisfies mild conditions, then $\pi_k(M,p)={\displaystyle{\lim_{\longrightarrow}}}(\pi_k(M_n,p),\pi_k(i_n))$ for $k\geq 0$, $p\in M$, $i_n\colon M_n\to M_{n+1}$ the inclusion maps and where ${\displaystyle{\lim_{\longrightarrow}}}$ here is the direct limit of groups.

Comment: I should add, they mention in the introduction that there is a weaker result which is well known, and which I think may apply to this case, so you may wish to follow those references to make sure.

Comment: You should specify which topology you are using. Is it the weak topology on a cell complex?

Comment: One can prove the contractibility of $V_k(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ directly by using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.